# SPParameters Not Matching Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, highcharts, parameters

I have posted this question in the Logi Analytics DevNet but it is a graveyard there and I am hoping I can get an answer here. I am using Logi Info v12.2.116.

I am using a stored procedure to get data to fill my reports. The stored procedure calls an RPG program. I have done this many times, but today when I created a new stored procedure, a new report, the parameters for some reason do not match up. I have restarted Logi as well... Sometimes it doesn't pick up new stored procedures until it reboots but that didn't work either. I have never seen this error before:

> The number of parameter values set or registered does not match the number of parameters

Here is the code for my parameters:

```
<DataLayer Type="SP" Command="myStoredProcedure">
<SPParameters NullValue="'">
<SPParameter SPParamDirection="Input" ID="GAct" SPParamSize="2" SPParamType="dt-129" Value="RE" />
<SPParameter SPParamDirection="Input" ID="rsDetail" SPParamType="dt-129" Value="N" SPParamSize="1" />
<SPParameter SPParamDirection="Input" ID="rsFromDate" SPParamSize="10" SPParamType="dt-7" Value="@ Request.paramFromDate~" />
<SPParameter SPParamDirection="Input" ID="rsToDate" SPParamSize="10" SPParamType="dt-7" Value="@ Request.paramToDate~" />
<SPParameter SPParamDirection="Input" ID="rsDepts" SPParamSize="256" SPParamType="dt-129" Value="@ Request.paramAllDepartments~" />
</SPParameters>
```

Here is the stored procedure definition:

```
1 IN GACT         CHARACTER 2   No default
2 IN RSDETAIL     CHARACTER 1   No default 
3 IN RSFROMDATE   DATE          No default 
4 IN RSTODATE     DATE          No default
5 IN RSDEPTS      CHARACTER 256 No default
```

What in the world is causing this problem? Yes I am connecting to the same partition/library. Yes the program and stored procedure work perfectly fine when being called outside of Logi. Yes I am calling the right stored procedure.

Comment: Can somebody please add a 'logi' tag? The reasoning is that the more and more people use Logi Info (Analytics), the more questions will be asked here. Logi has a developer forum on their website but it is absolutely horrible, and good luck trying to contact their support. It is also a specific software suite that isn't used by anything other than them. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just so you guys know, Logi Analytics uses the HighCharts API in the background.. thus the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<SPParameter SPParamDirection="Input" ID="GAct" SPParamSize="2" SPParamType="dt-129" Value="RE" />
```

To:

```
<SPParameter SPParamDirection="Input" ID="GAct" SPParamSize="2" SPParamType="dt-200" Value="RE" />
```

Char is generally considered to be a single character and is likely what is causing your issue. Also, unrelated, but I typically just use size 0 on all my SPParams to avoid truncation issues.